# How many nodes in Dense layer?

Tags: neural-network, keras

I have the follow Dense function and I am trying to understand it

```py
Dense(10, input_shape = (28*28, ), kernel_initializer='he_normal'))
```

Does the following code mean I have 10 nodes in my layer, or 28*28 nodes in my first layer. I asked a friend about this and they said it means you have a input layer of 28*28 that is followed by a hidden layer that has 10 nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your input is a 28*28 array and this dense layer has 10 hidden units with the following initializer for the layer weights: https://keras.io/initializers/#he_normal

Answer (score 0):

You friend was right - in fact, you have an *implicit* input layer of 28*28, followed by a hidden layer of 10 nodes.

This is more visible in the Keras Functional API (check the [example](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/#first-example-a-densely-connected-network) in the docs), in which your layer would be written explicitly as 2 layers:

```py
inputs = Input(shape=(28*28,))                         # input layer
x = Dense(10, kernel_initializer='he_normal')(inputs)  # hidden layer
```

See also my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46572674/keras-sequential-model-input-layer/46574294#46574294) in a relevant recent question.