# Building Neural Network- passing network as a prameter doesn't work in keras

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I am playing with Keras Code.  When i write the code like this,

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=(784,) ))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(784, activation='relu'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')
```

it works without any trouble. But If achieve this by passing the previous layer to next layer as a parameter, then i get the error.

```
layer1 = Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=(784,) )
layer2 = Dense(128, activation='relu') (layer1)
layer3 = Dense(784, activation='relu') (layer2)
model = Model(layer1, layer3)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')
```

Below is the error

```
ValueError: Layer dense_2 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor. Received type: <class 'keras.layers.core.Dense'>. Full input: [<keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x7f1317396310>]. All inputs to the layer should be tensors.
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: Please put a meaningful title to your question, the current one doesn't make much sense given the problem in the question body.

Answer (score 1):

You miss `Input` layer.

```
x = Input((784,))
layer1 = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
layer2 = Dense(128, activation='relu') (layer1)
layer3 = Dense(784, activation='relu') (layer2)
model = Model(inputs=x, outputs=layer3)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')
```

Comment: But there is something called input_shape as a parameter, that which carries input dimension. In that case when we need to write  a separate for Input() alone?

Comment: `input_shape` is optional except for the first layer of your model, since keras kindly guesses the input shape for middle layers from the previous.

Comment: If you use `Sequential` and `add` methods to create a model, you need to specify the input shape for the first `Dense` layer, since there is no clue to guess it.  This can be seen as a syntax sugar of `Input` + `Dense` in the functional API approach.

Comment: Yes, input_shape is only for Sequential models, for functional models you have to use the Input class

Comment: @Whoami indeed, there is a slight difference on how an input layer is handled between the Sequential & Functional APIs; see [Keras Sequential model input layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46572674/keras-sequential-model-input-layer/46574294#46574294)