# The input layer disappears from the structure of a deep learning model

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, deep-learning

I used the following code to create a CNN model using VGG16 but after creating the model, the input layer of the model disappears from the structure (see the image).

Why the input layer disappears from the structure?

```py
vgg16_model = keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16()
model = Sequential([])
 for layer in vgg16_model.layers[:-1]:
   model.add(layer)
   model.add(Dropout(0.5))
   model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax', name = 'prediction'))
```

The model structure

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is just an artifact of Keras model representation when the Sequential API is used, and it has no practical effect whatsoever: the `Input` layer is there implicitly, but it is not considered a layer proper and it does not show up in `model.summary()`. It *does* show up if the Functional API is used.

Consider the following two identical models, written using the two different APIs:

**Sequential API**

```py
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense      # notice that we don't import Input here...

model_seq = Sequential([
    Dense(64, input_shape=(784,),activation='relu'),
    Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])    

model_seq.summary()

# result:

_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 64)                50240     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 64)                4160      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 10)                650       
=================================================================
Total params: 55,050
Trainable params: 55,050
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

**Functional API**

```py
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Dense  # explicitly import Input layer

inputs = Input(shape=(784,))
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(inputs)
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
predictions = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(x)

model_func = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=predictions)

model_func.summary()

    # result:

Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         (None, 784)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 64)                50240     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 64)                4160      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 10)                650       
=================================================================
Total params: 55,050
Trainable params: 55,050
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

These two models are **identical**; the fact that the `Input` layer does not show up explicitly in `model.summary()` when the Sequential API is used does not mean anything regarding the functionality of the model. EDIT: As Daniel Möller correctly points out in the comment below, it is not even a real layer, doing nothing besides defining the input shape (notice its 0 training parameters in `model_func.summary` above).

In other words, no worries...

This relevant thread might be useful, too: [Keras Sequential model input layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46572674/keras-sequential-model-input-layer)

Comment: In addition, the input layer isn't really a layer. It does nothing besides defining the shape of an input. A layer "performs operations" on data. The input is just data.

Comment: @DanielMöller indeed - thanks for the useful input (added to the answer w/ credit)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an `InputLayer` explicitly...

**Sample Code:**

```
vgg16_model = keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16()
model = Sequential()
inp = InputLayer(input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
model.add(inp)

for layer in vgg16_model.layers[:-1]:
    model.add(layer)

for layer in model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()
```

**Output:**

```
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         (None, 224, 224, 3)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 224, 224, 64)      1792      
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 224, 224, 64)      36928     
_________________________________________________________________
block1_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 112, 112, 64)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 112, 112, 128)     73856     
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 112, 112, 128)     147584    
_________________________________________________________________
block2_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 56, 56, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 56, 56, 256)       295168    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 56, 56, 256)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 56, 56, 256)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 28, 28, 256)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 28, 28, 512)       1180160   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 28, 28, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 28, 28, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 14, 14, 512)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 7, 7, 512)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 25088)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
fc1 (Dense)                  (None, 4096)              102764544 
_________________________________________________________________
fc2 (Dense)                  (None, 4096)              16781312  
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 2)                 8194      
=================================================================
Total params: 134,268,738
Trainable params: 8,194
Non-trainable params: 134,260,544
```