# Dying ReLU problem when initial training data normalized

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have used training data which is normalised and consist of n features. The number of training examples are m.
I have implemented Deep Learning model Keras with the first layer as

```
model.add(layers.Dense(32,input_shape=(n,),activation='relu')
```

As my training data is normalised with mean 0 and std 1 should the neural network suffers from dying Relu problem as many data points have value less than 0 during training.

Should Relu be used in the first layer when the training data is normalised with mean 0 and std 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have explained [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46572674/keras-sequential-model-input-layer/46574294#46574294), in

```
model.add(Dense(32,input_shape=(n,),activation='relu')
```

when used as a first layer in the Keras sequential API (i.e. with an `input_shape` argument), there is an *implicit input layer*; this is more clearly shown when we write the same thing using the Keras functional API, i.e.:

```
inputs = Input(shape=(n,))                 # input layer
x = Dense(32, activation='relu')(inputs)   # 1st hidden layer
```

So, from this viewpoint, it is apparent that ReLU is *not* applied directly on your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't apply the relu directly on the input it should work!

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can you please help me on this one https://stackoverflow.com/q/62307806/12361444