# Multi class classification using InceptionV3,VGG16 with 101 classes very low accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to build a food classification model with 101 classes. The dataset has 1000 image for each class. The accuracy of the model which I trained is coming less than 6%. I have tried implementing NASNet and VGG16 with imagenet weights but the accuracy did not increase. I have tried using Adam optimizer with or without amsgrad. I have also tried to change the learning rate to both 0.01 and 0.0001 but still, accuracy remains in the single-digit.Please suggest the methods to increase the accuracy to at least 60 percent. Due to hardware restriction(Macbook air 2017) I cannot train very deep model.

Dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/kmader/food41

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3


train_data_dir=".../food_data/images"

data=tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
    featurewise_center=False,
    samplewise_center=False,
    featurewise_std_normalization=False,
    samplewise_std_normalization=False,
    zca_whitening=False,
    zca_epsilon=1e-06,
    rotation_range=45,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    brightness_range=None,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    channel_shift_range=0.0,
    fill_mode="nearest",
    cval=0.0,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    vertical_flip=True,
    rescale=1./255,
)
datagen=data.flow_from_directory(
        train_data_dir,
        target_size=(360, 360),
        batch_size=10,
        class_mode='categorical')


base_model = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet',input_shape=(360,360,3), include_top=False)

for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False


x = base_model.output
x = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu')(x)
predictions = tf.keras.layers.Dense(101, activation='softmax')(x)
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)

adam=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(
    learning_rate=0.001,
    beta_1=0.9,
    beta_2=0.999,
    epsilon=1e-07,
    amsgrad=False,
    name="Adam",
)

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit_generator(datagen,steps_per_epoch=100,epochs=50)

model.save('trained_food_new.h5')
```

Comment: If possible, try increasing the batch size. As you can see, a batch size of 10 when there are 101 classes might prove problematic.

Comment: I have tried increasing the batch size to 50. Should I increase it more than 100?

Comment: 50 images per batch should atleast get you out of 6% accuracy. You should also take a look at the augmentations you are performing to make sure the images aren't distorted to where the model can't train due to the added noise.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try to reduce the noise. Increasing the batch beyond 50 will not significantly increase the accuracy. My goal is to reach around 60 percent. I think to reach 60 percent accuracy architecture changes are required or model changes. This model performs very well for binary classification and where the classes are less than 10. But as the classes increase this creates a problem

Answer (score 0):

There are few that may improve the classification accuracy:

1. Use EfficientNet with noisy_student weights. There are less number of parameters to train. It gives better accuracy due to the scalable architecture it has.
2. You can use test time augmentation. In your test data generator, do a simple horizontal flip, vertical flip (if data looks realistic) and affine transformations. It will generate multiple views of the data and helps the model to average out more probable class.
3. Checkout imgaug library (embossing, sharpening, noise addition, etc.). Plus, there are random_eraser, cut out and mix up strategies that have been proved to be useful.
4. Try label smoothing. It can also help your classifier to give more probability to the correct class.
5. Try learning rate warmup. Something like this:

```
LR_START = 0.0001
LR_MAX = 0.00005
LR_MIN = 0.0001
LR_RAMPUP_EPOCHS = 4
LR_SUSTAIN_EPOCHS = 6
LR_EXP_DECAY = .8


def lrfn(epoch):
    if epoch < LR_RAMPUP_EPOCHS:
        lr = (LR_MAX - LR_START) / LR_RAMPUP_EPOCHS * epoch + LR_START
    elif epoch < LR_RAMPUP_EPOCHS + LR_SUSTAIN_EPOCHS:
        lr = LR_MAX
    else:
        lr = (LR_MAX - LR_MIN) * LR_EXP_DECAY**(epoch - LR_RAMPUP_EPOCHS - LR_SUSTAIN_EPOCHS) + LR_MIN
    return lr
```

6. You can also extract features and apply ensemble feature classification(XGBoost, Adaboost, BaggingClassifier) or triplet loss.