# What's the use case for explicitly specifying layer size in PyTorch?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network

From what I understand, for forward pass and backpropagation to work the size of the first layer must match the input data size. Then, the size of the second layer must match the output size of the first one and so on and so forth. This implies that the layer size can easily be inferred from its inputs, but PyTorch allows you to change the layer's input size to something else (unless you use torch.nn.Lazy*). What's the use case for this? Is using Lazy modules everywhere a bad practice?

Comment: "*the size of the second layer must match the output size of the first one and so on and so forth*" - not quite sure this is actually the case, but again I am not familiar with PyTorch; you may find my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46574294/4685471) for Keras useful.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of scenarios where you don't have a "previous layer" to specify the input size. Specifying the input size allows you to set it to whatever you need it to be.